# Updating a probability with additional knowledge. Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability, bayesian, naive-bayes

I am quite confused with using Bayes theorem for the following problem. And I am not sure it can be applied at all.

I have a football website data with user views. Each view corresponds to a specific team. Therefore, for each user I can calculate it's frequency and determine which football team he prefers.

Also, I have some geo statistics corresponding to football fans in different cites. With this I can calculate a probability of being a fan of specific team in some city.

Then with this additional information I want to update probability that a user likes some specific team.

I tried using Bayes Theorem for it but I am not sure if it is right.

P =  P(user likes the team) * P(Probability of liking this team in this city) /P(Probability to be a website user from this city)

Andy advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know which city the user is from?

Comment: Yes, I have city information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't quite make sense of your question. For one thing it seems that the geo
data would provide prior information and information from your website would 'update' that. I have tried to put your ideas into the framework of a typical application of elementary Bayesian inference.

Suppose that City A has a football team and several nearby cities also have football teams.
Your prior information (from geo statistics) is that *about* 40% of football fans in City A with favor the local 'A-team'. In Bayesian statistics the probability $\theta$ of preferring the A-team is provided as a probability distribution, often a [beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) distribution because beta distributions have $(0,1)$ as their support.

Perhaps you choose as your PRIOR distribution $\theta \sim \mathsf{Beta}(4,6)$ which has $E(\theta) = \frac{12}{12+18} = 0.4$ and puts over 70% of its probability in the interval $(.4,.6)$ and about 95% of its probability in
$(0.234, .0577),$ according to computations in R:

```
diff(pbeta(c(.3,.5), 12, 18))
[1] 0.7381535
qbeta(c(.025, .975), 12, 18)
[1] 0.2352402 0.5773954
```

[image]

Then from your website you find that $x = 1283$ of $n = 2500$ visitors to
the site from City A, show interest in the A-team. That information based on data
is represented in terms of a LIKELIHOOD function.

Bayes' Theorem in this setting is expressed as:

$$\text{POSTERIOR} \propto \text{PRIOR} \times \text{LIKELIHOOD},$$
where the symbol $\propto$ (read 'proportional to') indicates that
we are using 'kernels' of density functions, omitting their norming constants.

In particular, your posterior distribution is

$$p(\theta|x) = p(\theta) \times p(x|\theta)\\
\propto \theta^{12-1}(1-\theta)^{18-1} \times
    \theta^{1283}(1-\theta)^{2500-1283}\\
\propto \theta^{1295-1}(1-\theta)^{1235-1},$$

where we recognize the final expression as the kernel of the posterior
distribution $\mathsf{Beta}(1295, 1235).$

Thus, the posterior mean is $E(\theta|x) = \frac{1295}{1295+1235} =  0.512$
and the 95% Bayesian posterior probability interval is $(0.492, 0.531)$

```
qbeta(c(.025, .975), 1295, 1235)
[1] 0.4923767 0.5313210
```

Thus your prior information that $\theta$ is roughly $0.4$ has been
updated by website data to show that $\theta$ is very nearly $0.51.$

Comment: +1! Though it seems that OP has discrete case. There is a matrix `T x C`, with T - number of teams and C - number of cities, which has joint distribution. Than OP gets a fan info about views of teams (the new prior `P(T)`), but there is no information from which city the fan is. This fact brings up interesting question: can we add another prior distribution of a fan being from certain city and use two priors to get posterior about the team, some `P(T| C, C2)`, where `C2` is fans unknown location? (should we knew the city, the problems would be trivial - just to get `P(T|C)`.)

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for the confusion I brought and thank you a lot for your replies.

Actually, I know fans location. 

I will try to clarify the problem.

Comment: Let's say a user visited only 5 pages and 1 of them were with a specific football team - T.  I know that he is from a city C. And  I also know that 40% of all page views from the city C are about team T. 

Normally I would say that probability of the user to visit a page with the team T is  P(T) = 1/5 but then I know that an average probability for this city is much higher. And I want update P(T). Also, 5 visits is not enough to say if the user is interested in the team T or not.

Comment: Basically I am trying to predict a probability that the next page this users visits will be about the  team T. 

Thank you in advance for your answers, it is very helpful. I am still learning how to work with such problems and I find this problem quite interesting for myself.

Comment: @daLime, if so, your case is like in [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/readings/MIT18_05S14_Reading11.pdf). Feel free to write your answer when ready :))) or accept the existing one!

Comment: Thanks! Just found this one as well, it corresponds to one sent https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyuQsaqXhwU